# Jinja2 filter to find out is any value from a list matches with any value from another list

Tags: jinja2, home-assistant

I am looking for the way to perform the following filter and test without using any custom filters (just built-in filters only)?

```py
list1 = ['playing', 'off', 'off', 'off']
list2 = ['off', 'idle', 'paused']
```

I got these two lists and want to have a single line filter test where the result will be `True` or `False`. `True` if all items from `list1` matches with `list2` and `False` if at least one or more items from list1 **does not** matches with `list2`.

```py
# Example - 1:
list1 = ['playing', 'off', 'off', 'off']
list2 = ['off', 'idle', 'paused']    
result = False

# Example - 2:
list1 = ['playing', 'off', 'playing', 'off']
list2 = ['off', 'idle', 'paused']    
result = False

# Example - 3:
list1 = ['idle', 'off', 'paused', 'off']
list2 = ['off', 'idle', 'paused']    
result = True
```

Comment: What should be the result if `list2` contains elements not in `list1`?

Comment: I.e. `list1 = ['a', 'b']` compared against `list2 = ['a', 'b', 'z']`

Comment: actually `list1` needs to be compares with `list2` and if all items matched with list2 (that is there is no item which is not in `list2`) then the result is `TRUE` or else `FALSE`

for your given list the results should be `TRUE` as all the items in `list1` are available in `list2`

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution. The use of reject() filter solved it

```
{{ True if (list1 | reject('in', list2) | list | count) == 0 else False }}
```

this filter gives out the desired output

```
# Example - 1:
list1 = ['playing', 'off', 'off', 'off']
list2 = ['off', 'idle', 'paused']    
result = False

# Example - 2:
list1 = ['playing', 'off', 'playing', 'off']
list2 = ['off', 'idle', 'paused']    
result = False

# Example - 3:
list1 = ['idle', 'off', 'paused', 'off']
list2 = ['off', 'idle', 'paused']    
result = True
```